# Need help compiling data from form into specific tables

Tags: forms, google-sheets, filter, aggregate

I have some data that i receive through a google form that lists availability dates and times for different people.  I need to take those and fill in a chart with those available at each time segment for each day of the week.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19U157j5gwbg-7BJTQJ9KCB92huRgZybP_RBsHsK86q0/edit?usp=sharing

Data comes in on "Form"
"Data1" is my attempt at organizing the data
"Schedule" should compile each character and their time into the cells.  Cells will have multiple entries in them.

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm trying to use filters and sorts to get the data to go in the correct place but need some help making it work.

Answer (score 1):

delete everything in range G2:CL on your Data1 sheet and paste this into G2. then paste it into every next 4th column (K2, O2, S2, W2, AA2, ...etc.):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR($B2:$B*1)&{"2","3","4","5"}, 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(
 VLOOKUP(ROW($B2:$B), {ROW(Form!$B2:$B), Form!$C2:$AD}, 5+ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN()-3)/4), 0), ","))), 
 {"Monday",    2;
  "Tuesday",   3; 
  "Wednesday", 4;
  "Thursday",  5}, 2, 0), "-")),,9^9)), " ", "|")), 
 {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"}, ))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats definitely an easier way than I had!  What I needed more was taking that information and filtering it into the "Schedule" sheet.

Comment: The code you gave me left out the weekends on the far right columns after BB.  I tried to modify it to fit the weekends but  cant get it.  I redid the form to include weekends in the same cell instead of separate columns.

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR($B3:$B*1)&{"2","3","4","5","6","7","8"}, 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(
 VLOOKUP(ROW($B3:$B), {ROW(Form!$B2:$B), Form!$C2:$R}, 5+ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN()-3)/4), 0), ","))), 
 {"Monday",    2;
  "Tuesday",   3; 
  "Wednesday", 4;
  "Thursday",  5;
  "Friday",    6;
  "Saturday",  7;
  "Sunday",    8}, 2, 0), "-")),,9^9)), " ", "|")), 
 {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}, ))